# Passing structured array to Cython, failed (I think it is a Cython bug)

Tags: numpy, cython

Suppose I have

```
a = np.zeros(2, dtype=[('a', np.int),  ('b', np.float, 2)])
a[0] = (2,[3,4])
a[1] = (6,[7,8])
```

then I define the same Cython structure

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef packed struct mystruct:
  np.int_t a
  np.float_t b[2]

def test_mystruct(mystruct[:] x):
  cdef:
    int k
    mystruct y

  for k in range(2):
    y = x[k]
    print y.a
    print y.b[0]
    print y.b[1]
```

after this, I run

```
test_mystruct(a)
```

and I got error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-df126299aef1> in <module>()
----> 1 test_mystruct(a)
_cython_magic_5119cecbaf7ff37e311b745d2b39dc32.pyx in _cython_magic_5119cecbaf7ff37e311b745d2b39dc32.test_mystruct (/auto/users/pwang/.cache/ipython/cython/_cython_magic_5119cecbaf7ff37e311b745d2b39dc32.c:1364)()
ValueError: Expected 1 dimension(s), got 1
```

My question is how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: How is that a duplicate?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, could you please remove duplicate flag @CristiánAntuña . Thank you.

Comment: @hpaulj: it was a different question at first. Pengyu: comment removed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423207/accessing-numpy-record-array-columns-in-cython successfully passes a structured array to C packed structure.  And this finds a way around the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239091/cython-memoryviews-from-array-of-structs

Comment: @hpaulj, the problem is that if there is an array definition inside C structure, it will cause an error. I don't see how to get around this error in two posts.

Comment: In `tests/memoryview/numpy_memoryview.pyx`.  `def test_structarray_errors(StructArray[:] a):` tests a packed struct with `int a[4]`.

Answer (score 4):

This `pyx` compiles and imports ok:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef packed struct mystruct:
  int a[2]    # change from plain int
  float b[2]
  int c

def test_mystruct(mystruct[:] x):
  cdef:
    int k
    mystruct y

  for k in range(2):
    y = x[k]
    print y.a
    print y.b[0]
    print y.b[1]

dt='2i,2f,i'
b=np.zeros((3,),dtype=dt)
test_mystruct(b)
```

I started with the test example mentioned in my comment, and played with your case.  I think the key change was to define the first element of the packed structure to be `int a[2]`.  So if any element is an array, the first must an array to properly set up the structure.

Clearly an error that the test file isn't catching.

Defining the element as `int a[1]` doesn't work, possibly because the `dtype` removes such a dimension:

```
In [47]: np.dtype([('a', np.int, 1),  ('b', np.float, 2)])
Out[47]: dtype([('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f8', (2,))])
```

Defining the `dtype` to get around this shouldn't be hard until the issue is raised and patched.

---

The `struct` could have `a[1]`, but the array `dtype` would have to specify the size with a tuple: `('a','i',(1,))`.  `('a','i',1)` would make the size `()`.

If one of the struct arrays is 2d, it looks like all of them have to be:

```
cdef packed struct mystruct:
  int a[1][1]
  float b[2][1]
  int c[2][2]
```

https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/c4c2e3d8bd760386b26dbd6cffbd4e30ba0a7d13/tests/memoryview/numpy_memoryview.pyx

---

Stepping back a bit, I wonder what's the point to processing a complex structured array in `cython`.  For some operations wouldn't it work just as well to pass the fields as separate variables.  For example `myfunc(a['a'],a['b'])` instead of `myfunc(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general method to get the dtype for a c struct, but it involves a temporary variable:

```
cdef mystruct _tmp
dt = np.asarray(<mystruct[:1]>(&_tmp)).dtype
```

This requires at least numpy 1.5. See discussion here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2298