# Possible using python struct.unpack to keep specific values grouped?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, struct, binary

I created a parser for some complex binary files using `numpy.fromfile` and defining the various dtypes necessary for reading each portion of the binary file.  The resulting numpy array was then placed into a pandas dataframe and the same dtype that was defined for converting the binary files into the numpy array was recycled to define the column names for the pandas dataframe.

I was hoping to replicate this process using python `struct` but ran into an issue.  If part of my structure requires a value to be a group of 3 ints, I can define the dtype as `numpy.dtype([('NameOfField', '>i4', 3)])` and the returned value from the binary file is `[int, int, int]`.  Can this be replicated using struct or do I need to regroup the values in the returned tuple based on the dtype before ingesting it into my pandas dataframe ??  I have read the [python struct documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) and have not noticed any examples of this.

When using a dtype of `>3i` returns a result of `int, int, int` instead of `[int, int, int]` like I need.

Edit ...
Below is a generic example.  This method using `numpy.fromfile` works perfect but is slow when working on my huge binary files so I am trying to implement using `struct`

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    def example_structure():
        dt = np.dtype([
                 ('ExampleFieldName', '>i4', 3)
             ])

        return dt


    # filename of binary file
    file_name = 'example_binary_file'

    # define the dtype for this chunk of binary data
    d_type = example_structure()

    # define initial index for the file in memory
    start_ind = 0
    end_ind = 0

    # read in the entire file generically
    x = np.fromfile(file_name, dtype='u1')

    # based on the dtype find the chunk size
    chunk_size = d_type.itemsize

    # define the start and end index based on the chunk size
    start_ind = end_ind
    end_ind = chunk_size + start_ind

    # extract just the first chunk
    temp = x[start_ind:end_ind]

    # cast the chunk as the defined dtype
    temp.dtype = d_type

    # store the chunk in its own pandas dataframe
    example_df = pd.DataFrame(temp.tolist(), columns=temp.dtype.names)
```

This will return a `temp[0]` value of `[int, int, int]` that will then be read into the pandas dataframe as a single entry under the column `ExampleFieldName`.  If I attempt to replicate this using `struct` the `temp[0]` value is `int, int, int`, which is not be read properly into pandas.  Is there a way to make `struct` group values like I can do using `numpy` ??

Comment: Your question isn't clear; I think you need to add some code and/or examples.  For example `[int, int, int]` looks like a list, or is it a 1d array?  `int, int, int` is that a tuple, `(int, int, int)`, or something else?

Comment: @hpaulj ok will do

Comment: I haven't used the Python `struct` much, and not with `numpy`.  However this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035287/passing-structured-array-to-cython-failed-i-think-it-is-a-cython-bug `cython` question shows that there is a certain relatedness between `c` struct, python `struct` and `numpy` compound dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest just splitting it up into a list of objects after unpacking it. It won't be as fast as `numpy` for huge objects, but then that's why `numpy` exists :P. Assuming `data` holds your raw bytes that you want to split into groups of 5 `uint32_t`s (obviously the data must also be in this shape):

`import struct
output = struct.unpack("5I"*int(len(data)//5), data)
output = [data[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(data), 5)]`

Of course, this means iterating the data twice, and since `struct.unpack` doesn't `yield` successive values (afaik), doing it in one line won't help that. It'd maybe be faster to iterate over the data directly - I haven't run any tests - like this:

`import struct
output, itemsize = [], struct.calcsize("5I")
for i in range(0, len(data), itemsize):
    output.append(struct.unpack("5I", data[i:i+itemsize])`